# Can I convert a specialized killstreak weapon to a professional one without losing strange progress?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a specialized killstreak Australium sniper rifle with ~3000 kills. I'de like to make it professional, but ideally without losing the kill counter. Am I able to just apply the professional kit without worry?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Killstreak kits only track the kills made in the current life.  This isn't permanent information and is lost as soon as you die or leave a server.

The overall kill count is tracked because the weapon is strange... and all Australium weapons are Strange.

Comment: That doesn't answer his question though, does it?

Comment: @imulsion It didn't?  The 3000 kills aren't part of the killstreak, so...

Comment: @imulsion If it makes you happy, I added the word "Yes" to the answer.

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: @EpicGuy You mean other than Strange weapons predating Killstreak kits by 3+ years?

Answer (score 2):

When you go to "restore" an item, it gives you a list of all things that can be restored/removed. To make it Pro Killstreak, all you have to do it select remove Specailized Killstreak and avoid the button to reset the Strange counter. Then, you just apply the Pro KS kit normaly. As long as you do not trade the item or select the button that resets the Strange counter, the number of kills on the weapon will never reset.

The final answer for the question is yes.